# How I dynamically upgrade worker's cpu/ram/disk in dataproc?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a cluster by default setting(4 vCPUs, 15GB Ram) in google dataproc.
After working several pig jobs, the cluster had 2-3 unhealthy node.
So I upgraded the worker VM's vCPUs(4 to 8 vCPUs), Ram(15GB to 30GB) and Disk.
But in the Hadoop Web interface showed the hardware of worker node didn't change, it still showed the original mounts of vCPU/Ram/Disk.

How can I dynamically upgrade worker's cpu/ram/disk in dataproc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataproc has no support for upgrading workers on running clusters. To upgrade, we suggest recreating the cluster. You can also add extra workers via clusters update gcloud command.

It is possible to upgrade worker type by stopping each worker instance, upgrading and restarting. However, there are a number of hadoop/spark properties that have to change to accommodate different container sizes.

Comment: Thanks. I want to know how to configure hadoop/spartk properties to fit upgraded worker's HW spec. and to improve hadoop performance.

Comment: We're always optimizing properties for each dataproc and hadoop/spark release. Here's an example of how you could do it (but please don't do this on cluster creation): http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html

Answer (score 0):

We have to stop the Cluster and could edit the configuration to upgrade the CPU/RAM

Comment: This could be posted as a comment as it does not provide more information about the solution that the existing one.