# Resizing recommendation On Google DataCloud

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have set up a cluster of 24 high-memory CPUs (1 master: 8 vCPUs and 2 workers: 8 vCPUs). In the recommendation bar at the bottom of the first picture is adviced to resize the master-node to 10 CPUs, so 2 additional CPUs, because the master is overutilized. Nevertheless the graph in the first picture shows I have not been above a CPU utilization of 12%.

[image: Google DataProc Console]

Additionally when I go to the VM Instances page, another recommendation is made. It is advised to resize my master-node from a high-memory one to a standard one as show in picture 2. So according to this recommendation I should size my cluster down.

[image: Rommendation on VM Instance Page]

Is there someone who can give me a (logical) explanation of what I should do? 
I got the impression that my master and workers are not utilized at their full potential as often a lot of CPU-power is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as mentioned in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073032/how-i-dynamically-upgrade-workers-cpu-ram-disk-in-dataproc) Dataproc doesn't currently support live reconfiguring of the already-running Hadoop/Spark services when you resize machines through the Google Compute Engine interface. Dataproc is optimized to make it easy to run ephemeral clusters, however, so that the quick cluster deployment time allows you to easily experiment with other cluster shapes or newer Dataproc image versions.

For now, to try a new machine size you should create a new Dataproc cluster with the new settings. Looking at your historical CPU usage, I'd say the recommended upgrade from 8 cores to 10 cores probably isn't a strong enough signal as long as the brief periods of CPU overutilization don't appear to be causing any problems to your currently running jobs (in general Dataproc jobs are more likely to "overutilize" CPUs than, say, web frontend instances, and this doesn't necessarily mean you actually want more CPUs).

The recommended memory downgrade of the master seems close enough to an `n1-standard-8` that if it were me I'd just try an n1-standard-8 for the master node next time I deploy the cluster rather than going so fined-grained with a custom machine type.

If you really do want to try the custom machine types, Dataproc does support custom machine types when deploying with the `gcloud` command-line tool. [Here are the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/custom-machine-types) for specifying custom mix of CPU/RAM in a Dataproc command.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Dennis.